# Converting row from int to string

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to build a rest service with a predefines database and the problem is that IdCliente is a int type and I want to return a list of string.

Here is the code I'm trying to build

```
public List<Cliente> ListarClientes()
{
    try
    {
        var dt = (new DAL.DbHelper()).GetResultSet("SELECT idCliente, nomeUtilizador, password, tipoUtilizador, ativo FROM Cliente");
        var qCli = from dr in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   select new Cliente
                     {
                         (string)IdCliente = dr["idCliente"]
                     };
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

IdCliente is the `Int` and I'm failing miserably on doing this. The problem is that the db is filled with data so it would be a problem to do it all over again.. Any help please?

edit:

i tried this and i get no errors

```
public List<Cliente> ListarClientes()
{
    try
    {
        var dt = (new DAL.DbHelper()).GetResultSet("SELECT idCliente, nomeUtilizador, password, tipoUtilizador, ativo FROM Cliente");
        var qCli = from dr in dt.AsEnumerable()
                   select new Cliente
                     {
                         IdCliente = Convert.ToInt32(dr["idCliente"]),
                         NomeUtilizador = dr["nomeUtilizador"].ToString(),
                         Password = dr["password"].ToString(),
                         TipoUtilizador = Convert.ToInt32(dr["tipoUtilizador"]),
                         Ativo = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["ativo"])
                     };
        IdCliente.ToString();
        Ativo.ToString();
    }
```

But, is this correct ?

my original data

```
public class Cliente
    {
        int idCliente;
        string nomeUtilizador;
        string password;
        int tipoUtilizador;
        bool ativo;

        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public int IdCliente
        {
            get { return idCliente ; }
            set { idCliente = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public string NomeUtilizador
        {
            get { return nomeUtilizador; }
            set { nomeUtilizador = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string Password
        {
            get { return password; }
            set { password = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public int TipoUtilizador
        {
            get { return tipoUtilizador; }
            set { tipoUtilizador = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public bool Ativo
        {
            get { return ativo; }
            set { ativo = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is returning a List<Cliente>, not a List<string>: what do you want to return?

Answer (score 3):

You could convert the value to an Int32 before you convert the Int32 to a string;

```
string IdCliente = Convert.ToInt32(dr["idCliente"]).ToString();
```

...or you could use the ToString() method to convert the value to a string directly:

```
IdCliente = dr["idCliente"].ToString();
```

You cannot *cast* the value to a string though.

Comment: couldnt use any but i edit and it was the only was i dont have errors but i dont know if it is the correct way.

Comment: What is not the correct way? As mentioned you cannot *cast* a non-string value to a string but you can *convert* any value to a String using the ToString() method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select new Cliente
{
    IdCliente = (string)dr["idCliente"];
};
```

Comment: I still have the CS0029 C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' error with this.

Comment: I have edited my answer - If `dr["idCliente"]` it's already a string then you can cast the assignment that way

Comment: That is correct as long as `dr["idCliente"]` is always an integer, do you know if it's always an integer?

Comment: Yes its always an integer and ativo is always a bolean. my only question is, will this return a list of strings ?

Comment: It will return a `List` of objects of type `Cliente`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last edit, I think you are looking for a "conversion" from a string to an integer type.

Conversions like this are done through "parse" methods. You would do something like:

```
select new Cliente
{
    IdCliente = int.Parse(dr["idCliente"]);
};
```

It will only work if dr["idCliente"] is guaranteed to be a string with an integer value inside.

EDIT:

Ok, I think you are trying to serialize the return of your method. You won't be able to return a list of string using your method signature (it returns a List of Clientes (`public List<Cliente>`) and your Cliente class have ints and a boolean inside.

If you want to serialize it, you must tell us what is the output format you want it to (JSON, XML), if you are just trying to return your data in a key x value format, value being a string, you need to change your Cliente class so that your properties cast your variables to string (or you can change everything to string).

Comment: My IdCliente is an integer and i want to convert it to string in order to return a list of strings from my client. I edited with my original Cliente class

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're trying to set a **string** into an **int** property (`public int IdCliente`).
I suggest you to create a DTO if you really need to convert it to a string and return it as an object list. 
Example:

```
public class ClienteDTO
{
    string idCliente;

    public string IdCliente { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
select new ClienteDTO
{
    IdCliente = dr["idCliente"]
};
```